# How to enable/disable "click to go forward" button in browser using history js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-history, html5-history

Using `history.pushState`, we can change the current url using history API. Using `popstate` function, we can get back to previous page. But while going back, I found that the forward link button in browser "Click here to go forward" gets disabled. Now, using history, I need to access that button's property.

How can we access the forward button's url using history API?

Answer (score 2):

Are you manually popping the state? It sounds like it's getting removed.

To go back, you should be using `history.back()`. `history.back()` will preserve the entry in history so that you'll see the forward button enabled to go back forward.

You can also specify how many entries to go back with `history.go(X)`. ex: `history.go(-3)` will take you back three pages.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: I am using Ajax and just need my url to get change as in history.pushState(). history.back() simply loads the page in the history.

Comment: You wrote "But while going back, I found that the forward link button in browser "Click here to go forward" gets disabled"

If you use history.back(), then the forward will not get disabled... what are you doing at that stage? Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Can you give an example of a scenario and how you would expect it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer AJAX Method, when back(or forward) occurred all js variables(page scope) have old-values. firstly you product a JS variable with `time`(Server) then check this value by AJAX.when Hacker(Super-Beginner) want to access url via back/forward , this method show `alert('You are Hacker.Oops')` and change location.

page.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $expire=time()+120; // 2 minute
$expire_hash=md5($expire+'SECRET-KEY'); // optional for security purposes
?>
$.get('anti-back-forward.php?<?php echo "expire=$expire&expire_hash=$expire_hash"?>',
function(content){
   if(content=='BAD'){
      alert('You are hacker.Oops');
      window.location='index.php'; 
   }
});
</script>
```

anti-back-forward.php

```
extract($_GET);
if(($expire<time()) ||  $expire_hash!=md5($expire+'SECRET-KEY'))
   die('BAD');
echo "OK";
```